# converting segmentation mask numpy arrays for image segmentation using a deep CNN and a fully connected classifier

Tags: python, keras, conv-neural-network, image-segmentation, semantic-segmentation

I am building a model following a paper by Pereira et al for medical image segmentation, they use a convolutional network which feeds into a fully connected classifier.
I want to segment tumour from normal tissue.

I currently have a numpy array containing pre-segmented images [0]= background [1]= tumour, in the shape of 443, 443, 1 as the 'target', and images of shape 443, 443, 1 as the input.

How do I get the model to classify patches of the original image and then rebuild the entire image at the end to produce a segmentation map?

Thanks!

Comment: If you have a specific programming related question, you should provide some code and try to be as specific as possible to make it easier to get good answers.

Answer (score 0):

In case you refer to the paper "[Brain Tumor Segmentation Using ConvolutionalNeural Networks in MRI Images](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?arnumber=7426413)", they extracted patches of size 33x33 pixels from the original MRI scans and classified each patch to one of the 5 classes (normal tissue, necrosis,edema, non-enhancing or enhancing tumor) using the class of the middle pixels as ground truth.

In the end you classify each patch from one MRI image individually and keep track of their coordinates to build a segmentation map.

Comment: Hi thank you for your answer! I understand that they extracted patches I am just unsure of how to execute that in python. I do not have the original image data but a .pkl file containing numpy arrays of size 850 448 448 1 (number of images, height, width, channels) that need to be put into patches. Is there a best method to do this?

Comment: Let's say you like to have patches of size 33 as in the paper, just crop or pad you images, so that if you divide the size by 33, you'll get an integer number, e.g. crop to 429 or pad to 462. Then use numpy's reshape method: `np.reshape(data,(33,33,1,-1))` for each image.